# What is this kernal error when I make a python 3 jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just installed miniconda,jupyter notebook, python, and some packages.

I have the appropriate version of pywin32.

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
> "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py",
> line 1703, in _execute
> result = await result   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 742, in run
> yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py",
> line 69, in post
> model = yield maybe_future(   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 735, in run
> value = future.result()   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 742, in run
> yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
> line 88, in create_session
> kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)   File
> "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 735, in run
> value = future.result()   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 742, in run
> yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
> line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
> kernel_id = yield maybe_future(   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 735, in run
> value = future.result()   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 209, in wrapper
> yielded = next(result)   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py",
> line 168, in start_kernel
> super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py",
> line 158, in start_kernel
> km.start_kernel(**kwargs)   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py",
> line 301, in start_kernel
> kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py",
> line 248, in pre_start_kernel
> self.write_connection_file()   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
> line 468, in write_connection_file
> self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,   File
> "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
> line 138, in write_connection_file
> with secure_write(fname) as f:   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\contextlib.py", line
> 113, in **enter**
> return next(self.gen)   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py",
> line 435, in secure_write
> win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)   File "c:\users\kivix\miniconda3\envs\thematrix\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py",
> line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
> import win32api ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar issue yesterday. Try running this code in the CMD

```
conda install pywin32
```

and install it if you use Anaconda.